# What is difference between Flatten() and Dense() layers in Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have confusion between the two. Could someone please elaborate on it with some examples?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237124/role-of-flatten-in-keras

Answer (score 6):

Flatten as the name implies, converts your multidimensional matrices (Batch.Size x Img.W x Img.H x Kernel.Size) to a nice single 2-dimensional matrix: (Batch.Size x (Img.W x Img.H x Kernel.Size)). During backpropagation it also converts back your delta of size (Batch.Size x (Img.W x Img.H x Kernel.Size)) to the original (Batch.Size x Img.W x Img.H x Kernel.Size).

Dense layer is of course the standard fully connected layer.