# What does applying a layer on a model do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, keras-layer

I'm working with the `tensorflow.keras` API, and I've encountered a syntax which I'm unfamiliar with, i.e., applying a layer on a sub-models' output, as shown in the following example from [this tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/siamese_network/):

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model, layers
from tensorflow.keras.applications import resnet


target_shape = (200, 200)


base_cnn = resnet.ResNet50(
    weights="imagenet", input_shape=target_shape + (3,), include_top=False
)

flatten = layers.Flatten()(base_cnn.output)
dense1 = layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(flatten)
dense1 = layers.BatchNormalization()(dense1)
dense2 = layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(dense1)
dense2 = layers.BatchNormalization()(dense2)
output = layers.Dense(256)(dense2)

embedding = Model(base_cnn.input, output, name="Embedding")
```

In the [official reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Flatten) of `layers.Flatten` for example, I couldn't find the explanation of what does applying it on a layer actually do. In the `keras.Layer` [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) I've encountered this explanation:

> call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs): Called in **call** after making sure build() has been called. call() performs the logic of applying the layer to the input tensors (which should be passed in as argument).

So my question is:

What does `flatten = layers.Flatten()(base_cnn.output)` do?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But its' not quite what I was looking for - I wanted to know what does the application does under the hood, I mean does it add the model and use it on the forward path in the call method.As this syntax is kind of new to me, I wanted some intuition into why it works. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a model based on a pre-trained model. This pre-trained model will not be actively trained with the rest of your layers unless you explicitly set `trainable=True`. That is, you are only interested in extracting its useful features. A flattening operation is usually used to convert a multidimensional output into a one-dimensional tensor, and that is exactly what is happening in this line: `flatten = layers.Flatten()(base_cnn.output)`. A one-dimensional tensor is often a desirable end result of a model, especially in supervised learning. The output of the pre-trained `resnet` model is `(None, 7, 7, 2048)` and you want to generate 1D feature vectors for each input and compare them, so you flatten that output, resulting in a tensor with the shape `(None, 100352)` or `(None, 7 * 7 * 2048)`.

Alternatives to `Flatten` would be `GlobalMaxPooling2D` and `GlobalAveragePooling2D`, which downsample an input by taking the max or average value along the spatial dimensions. For more information on this topic check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237124/what-is-the-role-of-flatten-in-keras).