# I am getting an error while trying to learn Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

This is my code:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(60000,28,28),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation ="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(10),
])
```

This is the output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-dc603c39e27e> in <cell line: 1>()
      1 model = keras.models.Sequential([
----> 2     keras.layers.Flatten(60000,28,28),
      3     keras.layers.Dense(128, activation ="relu"),
      4     keras.layers.Dense(10),
      5 ])
TypeError: Flatten.__init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: you are missing input_shape=(28,28) instead of all the parameters you gave to Flatten

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the role of "Flatten" in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237124/what-is-the-role-of-flatten-in-keras)

Answer (score 0):

I think at the first layer, you're supposed to use `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer` for your input instead of `tf.keras.layers.Flatten`. `Flatten` is used to "flatten out" a multidimensional input into an onedimensional one (usually used to transition from a convolutional layer to a fully connected dense layer).

Your code should be:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape = (60000,28,28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation ="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(10),
])
```